# Question is an exact duplicate, but answer has not been accepted

Tags: support

What is the best way to handle a question with an exact duplicate that *has* a good answer, but the answer has not been accepted and has no upvotes?

This is the original question:

[nltk cant interpret grammar category PRP$ output by stanford parser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33207799/699305)

The problem was that `$` cannot be part of a grammar rule name, and the answer (by myself) shows how to add it to the list of allowed characters. The following new question is a clear duplicate; the OP even noted the related question, but didn't consider it the same because... the illegal characters were different.

[Generating PCFG from Universal tagset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43037697/699305)

I tried to cast a duplicate vote, but I cannot because the answer to the original has not been accepted and has no upvotes; and since I am the author of the answer, I cannot upvote it. Is there a recommended policy on such cases?

Comment: hmmmm I was so about to say "just upvote it"..... but.... yeah. If I knew the tech I'd upvote and let you close, but I'll leave that someone with the right knowledge

Comment: Yeah, the solution works and I'm pretty confident that it's a reasonable way to go about it, but I was hoping for a little more input from the nltk experts...

Comment: You could post on Meta so that you'll get upvotes ;-)

Comment: I was sort of counting on that :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you feel confident in your knowledge of the subject matter to know that the answer is correct, useful, solves the problem, etc. then you should upvote it, and after having done so, it would make the question a suitable duplicate target.

If you aren't confident in your knowledge of the subject matter to know if you should upvote the post or not, then you clearly aren't in a position to flag the post as a duplicate, because it's just been asserted that you don't know enough about the subject matter to say whether or not the answer is an adequate answer.

If you're sufficiently knowledgeable about the subject matter to know that the questions are asking the same thing, but feel that the existing answer provided isn't a quality answer, doesn't adequately answer the question, etc. then either post your own answer that *does* adequately answer the question (and then close whichever question you didn't answer as a duplicate) or if you aren't able to answer yourself, then do nothing and wait for someone else to provide a quality answer to one of the two questions.

Comment: The slight twist here is that the OP of this question is the OP of the answer on the possible dupe.

Comment: In this case adding comment like "this is same as ...." seem to be the only option - at least people who know about the subject can check answer there and vote on it plus possibly VTC if needed.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I'd aded such a comment already. Actually I'm puzzled why neither question got any attention, it's not an obscure topic. But finally someone did upvote (tiniest meta effect ever), so it's resolved.

Comment: Faced the same scenario today... But this answer doesnt exactly address the case when the dupe target answer belongs to the close voter. My answer was not in a high traffic tag though